# Set node state in a virtual tree

Tags: delphi, nodes, virtualtreeview

I have created a virtual tree with multiple node and I want to disable some of them. I've seen there's a `States` property of a node. Which is a property of a type `TVirtualNodeStates` so I've check what kind of states I can set and apparently `TVirtualNodeStates` is a `set of  TVirtualNodeState`.

`TVirtualNodeState` can be set to `vsDisabled` so I guess this is what i need to disable a node in my virtual tree.

But I can't do that. This is what I actually tried:

```
lNode := myTree.addChild(nil);
lNode.States := vsDisabled;
```

And it gives me the error

> incompatible types between `TVirtualNodeStates` and `TVirtualNodeState`

How can I disable a node then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write `Node.States := [vsDisabled];`, to make your code compilable. But this is not what you are supposed to do. There are node states that you must keep untouched and by the mentioned statement you would throw them away and set only the `vsDisabled` one. You wanted to write either:

```
Include(Node.States, vsDisabled);
```

or:

```
Node.States := Node.States + [vsDisabled];
```

Another option (that should be preferred) is setting the state by the `IsDisabled` property:

```
VirtualTree.IsDisabled[Node] := True;
```